# How different are these function from calculus point of view, f(x)=(x^2-4)/(x-2) and g(x)=(x+2)?

Tags: calculus

Can't we just simplify f(x) and treat it same as that of g(x)?

Comment: What is $f(2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For two functions to be identical, first condition is that their domain must be same.

What are the domains of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?

Comment: domains are different for those two functions, f(x) has all real number except 2 and g(x) has all real numbers as its domain. That concludes, both are not same function, doesn't it?

Comment: @Nature Exactly. You're correct.

Answer (score 2):

The functions $f=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ and $g(x)=x+2$ are identical except at $x=2$. The graph of function $f$ has a hole at $x=2$ while $g$ is continuous. So from calculus point of view, $g$ is "nicer" than $f$ as $g$ is differentiable everywhere while $f$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)$ is completely identical to $g(x)$ for $x\neq 2$

NOTE

you can always  define $f(2)=4$ as $x=2$

in this case the new $f$ is continuous

E.G. think to $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ at $x=0$